# How do I limit what the user can do in my slideshow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow

I'm looking to limit the user from clicking on the next button while the slideshow is in animation ( when the image is busy sliding during the delayed animate ) . 
How could I do this? Also how do I ensure the that delay speed will not change once the next button has been clicked?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#prev').hide();
        i=0;
        for(k=0;k<6;k++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            $('#pic').delay(4000).animate({top:'-=384px'},'300');
            $('.c_head,.c_body').delay(4000).animate({left:'-=170px'},'300');

        }
            for(j=4;j>0;j--){

            $('#pic').delay(4000).animate({top:'+=384px'},'300');
            $('.c_head,.c_body').delay(4000).animate({left:'+=170px'},'300');
        }

        }

        $('#next').click(function(){

        if(i<4){
            $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'-=384px'},'300');
            $('.c_head,.c_body').stop().animate({left:'-=170px'},'300');        

            i++;
            $('#prev').show();
                if(i==4){
                $('#next').hide();

                }

        }

        });

        $('#prev').click(function(){
            if(i>0){
            $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'+=384px'},'300');    
            $('.c_head,.c_body').stop().animate({left:'+=170px'},'300');
    i--;
    $('#next').show();
                if(i==0){
                $('#prev').hide();

                }   
            }
    });



    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `complete` event from `animate`.

```
       $("#next").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       $('#pic').stop().animate({top:'-=384px'},'300', function (e) {
              $("#next").removeAttr('disabled');
       });
```

Comment: first you disable the element and on the completion of animate function you enable it again

Comment: oh okay but why in '$("#next").attr('disabled', 'disabled');' is disabled written twice?

Comment: its a key value pair, you set disabled attribute with disabled value